# how to copy all applications from one linux machine to another

Tags: clone, clonezilla

I wonder how I can copy all applications from one linux machine to another? I have a "source" machine (Ubuntu 16.04) which has all the configurations, setup and many complex application installed on it. Then I have a new fresh "destination" machine (Ubuntu 17.10) which I want it to have the exact same setup, configurations and all software that are installed in the source machine. Any advice? I read some articles suggesting using Clonezilla, and others using `apt-clone` but I'm not sure what is the best way?

Comment: = 17.01 does not exist.  = you are, at some point, going to run into trouble matching a 16.04 machine with a 17.10 machine. The 2 technically could have different methods of using settings for the same software due to newer releases.  "but I'm not sure what is the best way?" There is no best way; only a way you prefer (and I might not). I would use puppetmaster myself but for 1 machine that is going to be serious overkill. Keryx might be an option (it is an off-line tool for installing) see https://launchpad.net/keryx

Comment: @Rinzwind if I used Clonezilla to clone a disk from the source 16.04 version and use it on the destination machine, then the destination machine will be version 16.04 and no longer 17.10, right?

Comment: Yes that would make itb16.04

Answer (score 1):

Clonezilla is a cloning tool. It will give you an exact duplicate. ie 16.04 on both  machines.

If you want to keep 17.10 on the second machine then apt-clone will make a list of all installed package on the sources machine. This list can then be used to install the same packages on the second machine. This will not copy configuration files.

Note: 17.10 uses wayland by default, which is radically different than Xorg (default for 16.04).